# Flutter run fail in andriod studio Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

Following are the dependencies added in pubspec.yaml

firebase_core: ^0.5.2
firebase_auth: ^0.18.3
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.3

I update the gradle-wrapper.properties like this: as seen somewhere as a solution to below issues.
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Firebase console shows the successful installation as below
[image]

Still we are getting below

E/AndroidRuntime(10914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6905)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6497)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6437)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1898)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7402)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
E/AndroidRuntime(10914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Please advice.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue just now, but by following the steps in '[Upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android)' managed to fix this.

Basically, you need to add the following to your `build.gradle` file in the android folder, in the dependencies section:

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```

Then in the app level `build.gradle`, where you've already added `com.google.gms.google-services` previously, add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Finally, in the dependencies section in the same file, add:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
```

This should now work. This is assuming you don't have any of the Fabric repository stuff in there, which you'll need to remove. The details are in that link.